# How to download RapidMiner JARs?

Tags: jar, rapidminer

I am new to RapidMiner and I want to download it's JARS to use in eclipse but I can't found it. I have seen  rapidMiner from github - but I don't know how can and what should I download.
please help me

Answer (score 0):

I'm not 100% sure but i think you can't get rapidminer jars because of its license model.

But what you can do is the following:

You can train your Model in Rapidminer, then use the following extention to export it as a .pmml.

https://marketplace.rapidminer.com/UpdateServer/faces/product_details.xhtml?productId=rmx_pmml

just add the extention via marketplace and use the "Write PMML"-Operator to create a pmml file of your model.

The pmml file can be included into your java programm with the following library:

https://github.com/jpmml/jpmml-evaluator

The link above explains pretty well how to use the library.

So you can't train your model in java but use the model you trained in rapidminer in your java code. Note that the "Write PMML"-Operator does not work for all available classifiers.